# Connecting multiple selected nodes (B-spline) - Corel Draw

Tags: vector, corel-draw, line-art

I'm trying to achieve a smooth path much like you would see as a trend line on a graph. I have maybe 500+ lines where I only need the path/line to use the top nodes of each line. How can I do do this? (without doing it 1 by 1)

Image of what I want to achieve attached.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... I am not sure but probably this can help:

I used the silhouette tool to make an outline that is some mm offset the original nodes.

[image]

Exported only the red portion to svg

[image]

which renders a text file that include a line like this:

> polyline class="fil0 str0" points="0,839 166,839 166,8 338,8 338,424 504,424 504,756 670,756 670,1171 831,1171 831,756 997,756 997,507 1169,507 1169,673 1335,673 1335,1171 1501,1171 1501,1752 1661,1752 1661,1669 1827,1669 1827,1337 1993,1337 1993,1171 2159,1171 2159,839 2492,839 2492,8 2664,8 2664,424 2830,424 2830,756 2996,756 2996,1171 3156,1171 3156,756 3322,756 3322,507 3494,507 3494,673 3660,673 3660,1171 3826,1171 3826,1752 3987,1752 3987,1669 4153,1669 4153,1337 4319,1337 4319,1171 4485,1171 4485,839 4657,839 "

I copied that to Excel to eleiminate each other node

[image]

And copied the resulting numbers into the svg again

> polyline class="fil0 str0" points="0,839 166,8 338,424 504,756 670,1171 831,756 997,507 1169,673 1335,1171 1501,1752 1661,1669 1827,1337 1993,1171 2159,839 2492,8 2664,424 2830,756 2996,1171 3156,756 3322,507 3494,673 3660,1171 3826,1752 3987,1669 4153,1337 4319,1171 4485,839

I imported this svg file back to corel and positioned over the original

[image]

You now have a path that you could smooth.

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly closer to the solution. It seems strange that someone hasn't created a macro or adaptation of the join curves.